# Making the 'Next' or 'Previous' button fade out/disappear when there are no more slides in a slider

Tags: jquery, slider

After trying numerous pre-made sliders, none of which worked exactly how I wanted or had conflicts with other code, I decided to try and make one myself.

Using this example as a base, http://rafbm.github.io/howtomakeaslider/

Everything works fine but there is one option I want to add that I found on another slider, http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/

Whenever you have reached the last slide the 'next' button fades away, letting people know there are no more slides after. (same applies when you load the first slide -> the 'Previous' button has faded out/disappeared seeing there are no slides before).

This is the code that applied that in the html of the SudoSlider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider({
           customLink:'a.customLink',
           prevNext:false
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I add that to the base example I'm using now?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Withou more of your code we're gonna be stuck!   Try making a jsfiddle to show us.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source of the sudo slider on their site?

Comment: I can't seem to edit my orignal post (too many links) so here it is in a comment: Made a fiddle of the base example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4DYKy/
But I think I screwed up somewhere because it isn't working?
This is a direct copy of the example code so it should work right?

Comment: @Gerben Jacobs, If I knew what to look for I would. :) (i'm not that familiar with JS)

Comment: @user2699534 - It look like someone suggested an edit on your post, please update it when you can (probably now).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
goTo: function(index) {
// filter invalid indices
if (index < 0 || index > this.li.length - 1)
return

// move <ul> left
this.ul.style.left = '-' + (100 * index) + '%'

this.currentIndex = index
},
```

to

```
 goTo: function(index) {
// filter invalid indices
if (index < 0){
    $('#your_left_button').hide();
    return
}else{
    $('#your_left_button').show();
}


if(index > this.li.length - 1){
    $('#your_right_button').hide();
    return
}else{
    $('#your_right_button').show();
}

// move <ul> left
this.ul.style.left = '-' + (100 * index) + '%'

this.currentIndex = index
},
```

Will basically hide your navigation elements when you get to the respective ends.

Comment: Remember to accept correct answers so that people know you have found what you are looking for